# Simulink linear adjustment

Tags: simulink

I am new to Simulink and try to achieve the following:
I have a signal which simulates output power of an engine. I now want to be able to change this power output to a new value.

My question: How do I implement a linear adjustment from the current output to the newly requested output? Linear in the sense of a constant rate of change, e.g. x Watt/second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this is probably the [Rate Limiter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/simulink/slref/ratelimiter.html) block.

If you cause a step-change in the demand, the rate limiter will take the demand as an input and produce an output with the rate of change limited to the rate specified in its dialog parameters.

There is a [dynamic version](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/simulink/slref/ratelimiterdynamic.html) if you want the maximum slew rates to be specified via signals.